# How to setup intellij server jvm argument with both special characters and space

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, arguments, special-characters

I am trying to migrate some of the pre-existing eclipse project into intellij. Previously I have keystore/truststore setup within the jvm setting of the server in eclipse, and they are recognized properly. Below are the arguments I need.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\temp\keystore-truststore\keystore.ks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\temp\keystore-truststore\trustStore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="DxI]L*@[;!U GxE?Ab,7h6/0su!" (this is just an example, not the one I'm using)
```

The above test setting work in eclipse, and I can start the server and perform mutual authentication with the remote host. However, when I try to set the same setting within VM Options in intellij local server config, following exception occurs.

```
=DxI]L*@[ was unexpected at this time.
```

and the server failed to start.

According to intellij configuration guide, I escaped the double quote, put double quote to escape the space for the keyStorePassword, but the server still won't start. Below are a few options I tried, but none of them work.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=\"DxI]L*@[;!U" "GxE?Ab,7h6/0su!\"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=\""DxI]L*@[;!U GxE?Ab,7h6/0su!"\"
\"-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="DxI]L*@[;!U GxE?Ab,7h6/0su!"\"
```

I also tried to add the above configuration directly in the server configuration (in my case it was jboss 5.1.0 GA, thus I added the lines in run.conf.bat), and it was not picked up.

I wonder what's the appropriate way to escape the password with special characters/space so that it can be parsed by intellij correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\temp\keystore-truststore\keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\temp\keystore-truststore\trustStore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
"-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=DxI]L*@[;!U GxE?Ab,7h6/0su!"
```

Basically, the whole VM argument wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the double quotation will be removed automatically by Intellij. So this issue remains.

Comment: I tried this out in my jetty configuration, and it worked. Intellij 2015 Ultimate.

Comment: I am using jBoss and Intellij 2016.3, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming that $JAVA_HOME is there:

```
sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -file my_root_ca.crt -alias my_root_ca -storepass changeit -trustcacerts -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```